# Find maximum container size C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

I'm trying to find a good solution for the following problem:

I want to implement a function that takes a variable number of container arguments and returns the size of the biggest container. Here is an example:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> vStr(2, "foo");
std::vector<int> vInt(1, 123);
std::vector<double> vDouble(3, 1.1);
std::list<char> lChar(4, '*');
// or even more container

size_t uiMaxSize = getMaxContainerSize(vStr, vInt, vDouble, lChar /*, ...*/);
```

in this case `getMaxContainerSize` should return 4, because `lChar` has the biggest size of 4.

I've already implemented this workaround using `cstdarg`:

```cpp
#include <cstdarg>
...
size_t getMaxContainerSize(int iCnt, ... )
{
  size_t uiMaxSize = 0;
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, iCnt);
  for(int i=0; i<iCnt; i++)
  {
    size_t uiTempSize = va_arg(ap, size_t);
    uiMaxSize = uiMaxSize<uiTempSize ? uiTempSize : uiMaxSize;
  }
  va_end(ap);
  return uiMaxSize;
}
...
size_t uiMaxSize = getMaxContainerSize( 4, vStr.size(), vInt.size(), vDouble.size(), lChar.size());
```

But with this I have to type `.size()` for every container and I also have to specify the number of containers. I also don't like to use C stuff in C++ programs and I'm asking myself if there is a better way to implement this. Maybe by using some class and overloading `operator<<()` so I can type something like this:

```cpp
MaxSizeFinder cFinder;
cFinder << vStr << vInt << vDouble << lChar;
size_t uiMaxSize = cFinder.getResult();
```

Do you think something like this is possible? Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Why on earth would you ever want to do that? But I'm sure it's solvable with a variable argument template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a variadic template:

```
template<typename... Conts>
std::ptrdiff_t getMaxContainerSize(const Conts&... conts) {
    return std::max({conts.size()...});
}
```

When you pass containers as arguments, the compiler will deduce a list of types for `Conts`. Each parameter of the function will be a `const <deduced type> &`*. Using `conts.size()...` expands to `conts1.size(), conts2.size(), ..., contsN.size()`, where `conts#` is each argument given to the function. It turns out `std::max` has a handy overload that you can delegate this to.

There are a couple key advantages of variadic templates over C variadic functions:

- They are type safe - the compiler is guaranteed to complain when types don't match, and you don't need a format string or anything.
- The function knows how many arguments were passed, and you can get it with `sizeof...(Conts)`.
- Nothing special happens to the arguments when going in. In a variadic function, `char` would be an `int` by the time the function has to pick it out, among others.
- You don't need to explicitly specify any of the types when you use the arguments. This means you can accept an infinite number of types instead of a predefined list (think `printf`'s format specifiers).

Finally, per the comments, the return type was changed to a signed type that mostly acts as the signed counterpart to `size_t` (sort of like the non-standard `ssize_t`).

---

To future-proof the answer, there will soon be a `std::size` for a more generic way to get a container's size:

```
using std::size;
return std::max({size(conts)...});
```

This expands similar to above: `size(conts1), size(conts2), ..., size(contsN)`

---

<sup>*Normally, parameter packs are used with `T&&...` with `std::forward` instead of `const T&...`. This would potentially buy you something with third-party classes that have a more efficient `size` function when the object used is an rvalue. However, it adds complexity in general for a low chance at any benefit.</sup>

Comment: Re the naming, consider the standard library functions `getsin` and `getcos`.

Comment: Re the result type, better make that a `ptrdiff_t` (as opposed to unsigned type). There's no point in encouraging bugs to creep in by repeating the historical mistakes of the standard library. That decision (unsigned) was taken in a very different day and age, where a single bit of address size mattered.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Sorry, I'm missing what you're getting at with `getsin` and `getcos`. I can change the return type, though. I tend to prefer signed types myself, I was just keeping the same type as the OP had. One might expect a function that compares container sizes to return the same type as those container sizes, too, rather than a signed counterpart.

Comment: @chris: Sorry, bad examples. I should have focused on `std::getmax`, which you're already using. Mea culpa!